# NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory usage

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to use `NSFileManager` to determine if an item is a file or a subdirectory.

This is what I have:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"exported"] error:&error];

for (NSString *filename in files) {
    NSString *path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];        
    BOOL isDir;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDir isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir){
        NSLog(@"%@ is a directory", path);  
    }
    else {
        NSLog (@"%@ is a file", path);
    }
}
```

I get "is a directory" for files as well as for subdirectories. I searched for similar SO questions and I see no difference between the code I found there and the code I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using the wrong path to test your files and directories

In your `fileExistsAtPath`: you are testing for `documentsDir` and not `path`

Correct this

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDir isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir)
```

To

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: path isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir)
```